# proper backup & restore mediawiki on ubuntu mate

Tags: mediawiki

I am trying to create a streamlined approach to backing up and restoring my MediaWiki.  My wiki is installed in folder `/var/www/html/mediawiki` and is running on an Ubuntu Mate 20.10 machine, MediaWiki verson 1.35.1, PHP 7.4.9, and mysql version `Server version: 10.3.25-MariaDB-0ubuntu1 Ubuntu 20.10`.

**Backup:**

1. I installed [automysqlbackup](https://websiteforstudents.com/backup-mysql-databases-automysqlbackup-ubuntu-17-04-17-10/) and configured it to automatically make gzip backups of my mysql databases, which go into an SMB mounted folder mapped to my NAS (`/mnt/wiki-backup`)
2. I manually zipped the entire MediaWiki folder with the following tar command.

   `tar zcvhf mybackupfilename.tgz /var/www/html/mediawiki`

**Restore:**

To make sure I could restore the wiki, I made a textual change to one of it's pages.  Then I restored the MediaWiki's sql database using the following command (which I ran from `/mnt/wiki-backup` where the backup `.sql` file was located) where `mediauser` is the admin name for my wiki database, and `mediadb` is the name of the database.

`sudo mysql -u mediauser -p mediadb < mediadb_2021-03-19_14h22m.Friday.sql`

Sure enough, this worked fine - and the page was back to what it was before I made my test textual changes.

**My Questions:**

1. Is all text for MediaWiki pages stored in the sql database, and all images stored in the MediaWiki folder structure (e.g. `/mediawiki`)?  From [this page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Restoring_a_wiki_from_backup) this seems to indeed be the case.
2. How do I restore the `/mediawiki` folder from the tar I created at step 2. above?  Would it simply be the following?

   `tar zxvhf mybackupfilename.tgz /var/www/html/mediawiki -C /var/www/html/mediawiki`

I'd appreciate any other constructive feedback on how best to do this.

Comment: 1. Yes, and all the images are in https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUploadDirectory, which is `{$IP}/images"` by default. However, `mediawiki` contains the *MediaWiki* installation and the extensions, which may take longer time to re-install than to restore from a backup.
2. You may also want to use `rsync` to backup and restore the files differentially.

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderMashin, so for normal wiki use (editing pages, adding images/files) I really only need to backup the sql database and the $wgUploadDirectory?  Assuming I make no changes to the MediaWiki like adding extension, modifying LocalSettings etc.

Comment: Yes, and I forgot the `LocalSettings.php`. It is wise to back it up, if even it is not modified since installation. It contains the database credentials anyway.